# How to call a method twice but return different variables

Tags: java, methods

Im trying to call a method twice in main:

```
    System.out.println(switchBool(b));
    System.out.println(switchBool(b));
```

This is the method I made:

```
    public static boolean switchBool(boolean b){
    b=true;
    if(b==true){
        b = false;
    }
    b=false;
    if(b==false){
        b=true;
    }
    return b;
```

The first time it is called it is supposed to return "false" and the second time it is called it is supposed to return "true" but for my output I keep getting:

```
    true
    true
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? I am a beginner at java.

Comment: You assign b = true in the first line of your method. Then you immediately test the value of b. Why do you expect it to be anything but true?

Comment: That is the thing with code: it always does what you tell it to do. And if you dont understand what it does, add print statements, or step through the code using a debugger. And NomandMaker is fully correct: your problem is that you **assign** a value to the incoming parameter, thus effectively **overwriting** the values you pass into the method.

Comment: And note: the really bad practice is to just use the SAME variable for everything. `b` is your parameter, but you assign values to it within the method, and then you use it as return value. Be careful about that - you rather avoid using the parameter to WRITE something into it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I didn't realize I was overwriting the value I was passing to the method.  I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong.
You are assigning the value of b to true yourself.

```
public static boolean switchBool(boolean b){
    if(b==true){
        b = false;
    }
    else{
        b=true;
    }
    return b
}
```

There are however other things I would like to suggest.

1. If you are going to call by value, you have to assign the value back to the variable
   eg.

   boolean b = true;

   b = switchBool(b);

Other option is to pass by reference. Check it out.

2. You don't need if else statements to reverse a boolean. Can use the not operator - !.

   boolean b = true;

   b = !b;

   //b is false now;

Answer (score 0):

The boolean `b` is a local variable and lives on the stack. Thus it is lost when the method `switchBool` returns.

You have two options to solve it. Either you can make `b` a static variable or you make `b` an instance variable and turn `switchBool` into an instance method.

I would recommend an instance variable.

```
public class BooleanToggle {

    private boolean value;

    public boolean toggle(){
        value = !value;
        return value;
    }

    // I put the main method here for simplicity. Usually it is put somewhere else.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanToggle booleanToggle = new BooleanToggle();

        System.out.println(booleanToggle.toggle());
        System.out.println(booleanToggle.toggle());
    }
}
```

The result will be

```
  true
  false
```

We moved `b` from the stack to the heap so it can survive method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but there are multiple ways to do it. One way is the following.

```
public static boolean switchBool(boolean b){
        return !b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = switchBool(true);
        System.out.println(b);
        b = switchBool(b);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

In your example, you are not storing the return value. As in the main method, I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you can simply toggle the state of your boolean with `!` (the [Logical Complement Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)), and then return the value.  There is no need for the `if...else` block.

But...you need to assign the return value back to your original variable if you want to store that change outside the function.

So your function will look like this:

```
public static boolean switchBool(boolean b){
    b = !b; // toggle the state of b
    return b; // return the new state
}
```

In the calling code:

```
boolean b = true; // initial state of true
b = switchBool(b); // store the return value back in the original value
System.out.println(b); // print out the new state
b = switchBool(b); // store the return value back in the original value
System.out.println(b); // print out the new state
```

Output:

```
false
true
```